# How to properly implement "isLoading" in a parent component

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to create a reusable component that may contain various children that might require loading data. The parent component doesn't (and should not) know, if any childs need to fetch additional data. It looks like this:

```
function MyPage(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <WidgetA/>
      <WidgetB/>
      <WidgetC/>
    </>
  );
}
```

Now, instead of showing 3 spinners for each individual widget, I'd like to show just one spinner for the whole page. Also, when there is no data available (none of the childs returned any HTML), I'd like to show another component saying something like "There is no data available".

I've already tried a simple idea, namely to return `null` from a child to indicate that it isn't ready yet.

```
function MyPage(props) {
  const widgetA = <WidgetA/>
  if(!widgetA) {
    return <div>Loading</div>
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <WidgetA/>
    </div>
  );
}

function WidgetA() {
  // ...
  if(loading) return null
}
```

However, this does not work because I am unable to determine whether a component is returning something or not. The component is never null, `React.Children.count` doesn't work and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ternary condition for this- Sample app

```
function MyPage() {
     const [isLoading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
     React.useEffect(()=>{
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(res=>res.json())
      .then(res=>{
        setLoading(false)
        console.log(res)
      })
     },[])
      return (
        <div>
          {!isLoading ?
         <>    
          <WidgetA/>
          <WidgetB/>
          <WidgetC/>
         </>:<h2>Loading....</h2>
          }
        </div>
      );
    }
```

`isLoading` will be set true/false as per your condition like fetching api or inside click function you can set true/false.

Live working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-goodall-py7nw) to use loading.

Comment: But where to get `isLoading` from? That's the whole point. The `MyPage` component shouldn't care about what data is needed by the child components because I'd like to make it as easy as possible to swap children in that component.

Comment: @K.D. check now... posted with example of live demo

Comment: Thank you, but the data fetching logic *should not* take place within the parent component, because the component should be flexible. Children should be added and removed easily without changing the data-fetching logic and prop-drilling

Answer (score 0):

Use some central store management like **redux**. And call that loading variable in header component which is common for all three child components.

Make api calls from **redux** and toggle **isLaoding** variable on api calls.

Your job done.

Comment: Thank you very much. I know Redux very well but I can't see how it would solve my problem. Even if I'd implement the fetching logic with Redux, the parent component would have to know what selectors / actions are required for the children and I don't want that dependency.